# Is it possible to implement localization in clojurescript by using react-intl library?

Tags: reactjs, localization, clojurescript

I am trying to implement localization in a clojurescript file.But I want to implement it using react-intl library.Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can, I created this [small repo](https://github.com/dfuenzalida/cljs-react-intl) with an example right out of the react-intl documentation. Check this screenshot:

[image: react-intl clojurescript example]